# Deleting sublists based on a criterion

Tags: combinatorics, list-manipulation

I generated a list as follows

```
m=7;
pinv=5;
p=1/pinv;
permutations=Permutations[Join[ConstantArray[1,m-1],ConstantArray[0,pinv]]]
numberofhypothesis=Binomial[pinv+m-1,m-1];

hypothesisset[index_]:={p*Max[Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],1]-1],p*Max[Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],2]-Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],1]-1],p*Max[Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],3]-Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],3]-1],p*Max[Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],4]-Part[Position[Part[permutations,index],1],3]-1]};
hypothesissets=Array[hypothesisset,numberofhypothesis]
```

Next, I wanted to remove those sublists that had entries greater than 1. I tried looking up DeleteCases and Select, but it was hard to write out the condition. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Oops, yes, let me see if I can edit it

Comment: `DeleteCases[data, _List?(Max[#] > 1 &), {-2}]` or adjust the level spec as needed.

Comment: Could you please consider changing the title? It is in contradiction with what you describe in the OP. Perhaps "Deleting a sublist based on a criterion" is more appropriate. And I almost forgot...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thank you, and edited!

Answer (score 1):

If I run

`Position[Flatten[hypothesissets], _?(# > 1 &)]`

> `{}`

which means that there is not a single element for which it holds

> `element > 1`

within said list.

I am assuming that I understood the question properly, so with the following toy matrix that contains elements bigger than 1

```
test = {{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 1/2}, {1/3, 1/6, 
    1/9, 1/11}};
```

this works

```
Select[test, Max[##] <= 1 &]
```

> `{{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4}, {1/3, 1/6, 1/9, 1/11}}`

If the author of the OP meant to delete a sublist if an element appears more than once, the following does the trick.

Assume the toy model

```
test = {{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 2, 1/2}, {1/3, 1/3, 
    1/3, 1/11}};
```

and then

```
Select[test, Signature[#] != 0 &]
```

gives

> `{{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`

Comment: `Select[test, Max[#] <= 1 &]` also works.

Comment: @AsukaMinato thanks for pointing this out! Really nice!

Comment: Thank you for all your help! With the solutions, I managed to solve my Bayesian Learning problem